# Any disadvantages to Javascript inside the page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, node.js

In my build (for a complex webapp), I've aggregated all the javascript into 1 file, which I'm loading as script.js

I thought I might go even further and just print all the js into html. Are there any reasons I should not do that? My thinking is... why not just save the request?

The only downsides I'm aware of are:
I understand that since the js is pretty huge, the initial page load might get slowed down.

I'm not very concerned about that since the page is empty anyway without javascript.

Also the script.js could be cached. If I wanted to cache the script within the html, I would have to use varnish or the like.

What are some reasons why I should not do this? Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention that this is a 1 page javascript app, so every single page has the same javascript (and html).

Comment: "_I'm not very concerned about that since the page is empty anyway without javascript._" - well I'd be concerned about the people with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @Czechnology if you have javascript disabled you can't use the app anyway, I don't see any need to serve those people.

Comment: @Harry - that's not a very nice way to think about the blind and low-vision users who are restricted to using screen readers to navigate the web.

Comment: @tvanfosson. If it's a complex app then you can't treat the blind or the low-vision. Does google maps have a version that works with javascript disabled? Does google map work for the blind?

Comment: @Czechnology I wouldn't, there is no real reason to disable JS, except rare and often over-hyped exploits.

Comment: @Raynos - complex apps can and are used by low vision users.  Our campus course management system has a gold rating from the National Federation for the Blind.  It's not necessarily easy but it can be done.  In some cases you could be violating the law by not having your web sites be accessible, at least in the US.  And, while they may not have maps (most blind people aren't driving, I hope), they do have accessible search: http://labs.google.com/accessible/

Comment: Sites that aren't (yet) legally mandated to comply with accessibility guidelines *are* now starting to be sued by groups such as the National Federation for the Blind.  We're reaching the point where you are taking a financial risk when you decide to blow off accessibility.

Comment: @StephenP That's just wrong. Why should I as a developer have to extend my client target by law. Don't I have the right to choose how accessible my application is and lose a small market share

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use one single minified external js file. As a seperate file it can be cached nicely, although an extra HTTP request is needed.

If you put your java script inline then it wont be cached as simply and you will have duplication of code on every page if you are reusing methods that are inline.

Comment: Doesn't at all answer the question?

Comment: @Harry this answer does address the question, just not directly. @Andi +1 cause your right.

Comment: @Unkwntech That's what I have right now, the question is about whether or not I should go one step further.

Comment: @Harry the caching thing is **huge** and the #1 reason to **not do** what you're thinking of doing.

Comment: @Pointy I was under the impression that it's fine to just cache the html instead of the script? In the end there's no difference? From a caching perspective.

Comment: You've got a "complex web app" where the HTML is a static file?  Well, if that's the case, and your server "actions" are all just returning JSON or something, then you'd be OK with a single static file. Most web applications do a lot of server-side template work, but not all do. Apps that really are "all client" for presentation are still kind-of rare, but if that's what you've got then it's cool.

Comment: @Point really? I thought that was the new trend nowadays. The server does return empty templates sometimes :) but the actual templating uses underscore templates. But thanks.

Comment: @Harry I guess it's pretty trendy, but that doesn't (by itself) make it that common :-)  It's one of those things that a lot of people talk about but which is not always done. Now that there are nice template systems for client-side JavaScript things are a lot easier I guess!

Answer (score 2):

Give the credit to Andi - this is what they meant, if I may be so presumptuous.

It's better form to have the file external because it simplifies caching. Allows it to be easily minified for lighter transport and makes maintaining the JavaScript it self easier.

Answer (score 2):

There are **many** reasons to separate javascript code from HTML (if not just for "best practice" purposes), but there is one big one that is very important in this situation.

Caching.  When it is in another file (such as "script.js"), that file will be cached after the first page load and will, therefore, not be read from the server until the cache expires.  If you put it into the HTML, the javascript will be reloaded every single time.  Varnish is simply an HTTP accelerator on the *server-side*.  It does **not** modify the cache of the client at all, so all the data will still be sent.  Varnish will just not reparse the data on the server (server scripting (PHP/ASP/etc), **not** client scripting (javascript)).  This is the biggest point to learn about this issue.  All the code will continually be resent to the client, which will greatly hinder the load time.

In addition, it is really only important to split them up among different files if:
A) One file will be changed a lot more frequently than the others (caching reasons again)
B) If you plan to use some functions on some pages (and not all on every page).  It is unnecessary to make the javascript interpret the function headers (only really the function headers due to lazy execution) of functions that it never uses on that page.
C) It is easier for organizational purposes.

Finally, browsers actually load multiple pages concurrently.  If you have an "index.html" page and a "script.js" page, they will both being loading concurrently and, therefore, begin execution faster.  If you split "script.js" into three files (lets say "script1.js", "script2.js", and "script3.js"), the browser will load these pages concurrently and, thus, begin execution even *faster* than just one script.js file.  Most browsers have a default concurrent page loading value of "3", meaning it will only load 3 pages concurrently, so it does not make sense to split something into tons of files instead of just a couple.

I hope I have made it clear why you should separate your javascript from your HTML (especially if you are making a large webapp in javascript).

Comment: Thanks for explaining it clearly. However since my HTML is tiny, it doesn't matter that it's not loaded concurrently as the javascript. My feeling is that a request will take longer than the html to download. I assumed that it's possible to cache html with etags or expires? I'm not totally 100% on how they work, but if it's not possible then what I'm proposing wouldn't be good at all.

Comment: If your HTML code is really that tiny to be worried that the headers will be bigger than the code, then I guess it wouldn't hurt that much to put it all in one page even though it is bad practice. I don't understand why you are so driven on making it all in one page, but go for it if the headers aren't negligible. It is possible to cache the page with etags and such, but make sure to have it expire when you want the page to be updated. Personally, I would still separate them into at least two files, but either way, for your situation, should work about the same according to the info you gave

Answer (score 1):

This might work pretty well for a single page web site, but it's not going to work very well if you need to share that code among several web pages or in an app with several url endpoints.

Comment: @Harry - If it's always going to stay that way, then I don't see why you couldn't include it in the page.  I'm assuming that the whole page would be ok being cached, i.e., there's no server side data being generated when loaded.  Note, you may have to go away from this if you change your architecture.  And, I don't think you'll gain much if the page is as empty as you say.

Comment: Thanks, well changing it is no big deal, it's only a line or 2 in my assets script. I understand it's not going to make a huge difference in my case, but still just want to do it right. :)

Answer (score 0):

All scripts that are necessary to run before the body loads should be placed in the `<head>` section. Furthermore, scripts that need to run AFTER the body loads should also be placed in the `<head>` section but inside a `document.onload` wrapper. Having this wrapper will ensure that you have access to the elements on the page since it will run **after** the body is rendered.

If you need to run scripts which need to execute as the body loads, you can place inline `<script>` tags inside the body, as they will execute ***while*** the page is rendering. This is useful in scenarios where you need to adjust widht/heights on some elements but don't want to have the ***jump*** that would happen if you placed it inside the `document.onload` wrapper.

Don't forget to combine and compress all scripts that are in the `<head>` section since this will ensure a faster page load and it will also get cached by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is client-side caching of your JavaScript file desired in your case?  If so I'd lean towards a separate file.